# Get chat data and sort by receiver and sender id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multidimensional-array

I've got a question.

I've got a database like this:

```
messages_id | int | Auto-increment
from | int
to | int
message | text
```

Now I have problems with grouping them by sender ID. I only want to retrieve the messages that are send or received by the user that is logged in. That's not too hard.

`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from = 1 OR to = 1 ORDER BY messages_id ASC`

But now, they are not grouped. As different people can message this user. I do not really know where to start.

I want something like this:

```
array(
    [5] => array(
        [0] => "message One",
        [1] => "Message two"
    ),
    [32] => array(
        [0] => "message One",
        [1] => "Message two"
    )
);
```

The 5 and 32 are the ID's of the people who's been chatting with.

Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: That means user 1 has been chatting with user 32 & 5...right?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all reply's. Really apreciate it, but I figured it out myself already ;)

Now I got the following:

```
$currentUserID = get_current_user_id();
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from` = '" . $currentUserID . "' OR `to` = '" . currentUserID . "' ORDER BY `messages_id` ASC");

$messages = [];

foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($row->from == $currentUserID) {
        $messages[$row->to][] .= $row->message;
    }
    else {
        $messages[$row->from][] .= $row->message;
    }
}
print_r($messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this a few years back. I did this:

```
select 'In' as MessageDirection, `From` as Contact, `To` as UserId, Message 
from Messages
where `To` = 1
union
select 'Out' as MessageDirection, `To` as Contact, `From` as UserId, Message 
from Messages
where `From` = 1
order by Contact
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Assuming each field must have either`Auto-increment_from` or `to`. And for received case `to` field has value

```
SELECT *, if(`Auto-increment_from` = 1 , 'From' , 'From') as meaage_type 
FROM messages WHERE from = 1 OR to = 1 ORDER BY messages_id ASC
```

Comment: I have updated it.Please review let me know your feedback.

Comment: Hi Dipanwita. Thanks for your efforts. But I already figured it our myself with PHP. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ok, no issue.Thanks.